# Can I do a "post" action on success of Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, post, hidden-field

I have the below code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "./api/v1/bluemix/auth",
    data: datas,
    success: function(data){

            var successUrl = "CreateBluemixMonkey.jsp"; 
            window.location.href = successUrl + "?data=" + newdata ;

                },
                error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {
                 alert("Error");

                }
})
```

After a successful AJAX call, I am setting `window.location.href`. Instead, can I do another post to the same JSP? I am trying to use hidden values but I doubt since there is no post method. I am getting all hidden field values as `null` in CreateBluemixMonkey.jsp.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "there's no post method."

Comment: Under success function, I am navigating to "CreateBluemixMonkey.jsp" using location.ref and not an Ajax post. I am looking for something like nested ajax. that is : An ajax call on success of first ajax function

Comment: Why can't you just do that?

Comment: Yes!! :)  I can try that . Only after I put my logic into words the solution struck me !!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a  on the page with some hidden inputs and then invoke the submit-method. This way you generate a POST-Request instead of a GET-Request, which is generated from the window.location.href code line.

If possible, just create a static  on your page which is hidden, preferably by setting `'display: none;'` as CSS-Style. Then give the form-tag an ID and run `$('#form-id').submit();` in your success-function.